# How to do - SQL Update scenario using Join condition on multiple columns and exclude column in join condition if null

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have 2 tables A & B, need to update UCode of Table A with UCode of Table B using c1, c2, c3, c4 as join conditions. tricky part is I should ignore not null columns from Table b on the join condition 
for example shown below, table B join condition should consider 4 columns for 1st row , only 3 columns for 2nd row, only 2 columns for 3rd row and so on

**Table A**

```
 ID   UCode    c1    c2    c3   c4
 100           abc   xy    pq   rs
 200           ab    bc    cd   ef
 300           aa    bb    cc   
 400           uu    pp    kk   mn
```

**Table B**

```
 c1    c2    c3  c4    UCode
 abc   xy    pq   rs   UC11    
 ab    bc    cd        UC22    --Ignore c4 on join condition
 aa    bb              UC44    --Ignore c3,c4 on join condition
 uu                    UC55    --Ignore c2, c3, c4 on join condition
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your desired outcome, but i think that you can put some checks on Table B columns in the join condition:

```
declare @tableA table (ID int,  UCode varchar(10), c1 varchar(10), c2 varchar(10),c3 varchar(10),c4 varchar(10))
declare @tableB table (c1 varchar(10), c2 varchar(10), c3 varchar(10),c4 varchar(10), UCode varchar(10))

insert into @tableA
values
  (100, null, 'abc', 'xy','pq',   'rs' )
 ,(200, null, 'ab' , 'bc','cd',   'ef' )
 ,(300, null, 'aa' , 'bb','cc',   null )
 ,(400, null, 'uu' , 'pp','kk',   'mn' )


 insert into @tableB
values
 ('abc',   'xy',     'pq'   ,'rs' ,'UC11')    
,('ab' ,   'bc',     'cd'   ,null ,'UC22')  
,('aa' ,   'bb',     null   ,null ,'UC44')    
,('uu' ,   null,     null   ,null ,'UC55')    

update
    @tableA
set UCode= b.UCode
from 
    @tableA as a
        inner join 
    @tableB as b 
        on 
        a.c1=b.c1 
    and (b.c2 is null or a.c2=b.c2) 
    and (b.c2 is null or a.c2=b.c2) 
    and (b.c3 is null or a.c3=b.c3) 
    and (b.c4 is null or a.c4=b.c4)
```

After the update statement Table A looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Andrea, will try this